# t-sql query to fill the null values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, cascade

I am a newbie to sql server 2012 and would like to find out how to create the following output using t-sql. there are many club numbers so there has to be a loop or cursor. Please help!!

Tables

```
club_number  name                                             number
---------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
355292     NULL                                               NULL
NULL       Giviton Mbunge                                     355308
NULL       Etero Aaron                                        355317
NULL       Evason Banda                                       355326
NULL       Kachibobo Batoni                                   355335
NULL       Kashamba Nkhani                                    355344
355353     NULL                                               NULL
NULL       Daniel Banda                                       355362
NULL       James Aaron                                        355371
NULL       Amson Kamanga                                      355380
NULL       Gostino George                                     355399
355405     NULL                                               NULL
NULL       Yohane Zimba                                       355414
NULL       Haward M.Chilembwe                                 355423
NULL       Zikiele Blangete                                   355432
355441     NULL                                               NULL
```

**Result:  I would like to see the above TABLE as below, which query can do it? please help**

```
club_number  name                                             number
---------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
355292       NULL                                               NULL
355292       Giviton Mbunge                                     355308
355292       Etero Aaron                                        355317
355292       Evason Banda                                       355326
355292       Kachibobo Batoni                                   355335
355292       Kashamba Nkhani                                    355344
355353       NULL                                               NULL
355353       Daniel Banda                                       355362
355353       James Aaron                                        355371
355353       Amson Kamanga                                      355380
355353       Gostino George                                     355399
355405       NULL                                               NULL
355405       Yohane Zimba                                       355414
355405       Haward M.Chilembwe                                 355423
355405       Zikiele Blangete                                   355432
355441       NULL                                               NULL
```

Comment: The mapping you describe is dependent on the sequence in which the rows are produced; but you do not describe how that sequencing is obtained.

Comment: @Pieter if you `COALESCE(number, club_number)` (or the opposite) it is in that order.

Comment: @Aaron:Yes; but OP should learn to provide a complete problem decription. OP is making us "guess" that critical fact.

Comment: Apologies for not being more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT club_number = MAX(club_number) OVER 
    (
      ORDER BY COALESCE(club_number, number)
      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
    ), 
  name, number
FROM dbo.your_table
ORDER BY club_number;
```

Comment: @user2148689 no problem. PS no loop, no cursor. Don't jump to conclusions like "there has to be a loop or cursor."